# Applying for loop in R to compute frequency distribution

Tags: r, rstudio

Suppose I have a data frame with several categorical features. How do I compute freq distribution table using for loop instead of finding individual distributions

I used the following code:

> 

```
data
         a   b  c  
1  class 1   1  M 
2  class 2   0  F 
3  class 3   0  M 
4  class 1   1  F    
5  class 1   1  F
6  class 2   1  M    
7  class 1   0  F   
8  class 1   0  F 
9  class 2   1  M    
10 class 2   1  M 
11 class 3   1  F    
12 class 3   0  F    

>b<-data$b
>b.freq<-table(b)
>b.freq

0  1
5  7
```

I want to do this for all the variables in a larger set with for loop.

Please help

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to apply the `table` function to all columns, you can use `lapply`:

```
> lapply(data, table)
$a

class 1 class 2 class 3 
      5       4       3 

$b

0 1 
5 7 

$c

F M 
7 5
```

*Update: How to create the plots:*

```
par(mfrow = c(1, length(data))); 
lapply(data, function(x) barplot(table(x)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You Sven :) ...Is it possible to simultaneously plot these distributions ?

Comment: @user3718501 Do you want them to appear in one plot?

Comment: side by side in one fig

Comment: one quick question: how can we do the same thing using for loop

Comment: @user3718501 You can do `for(i in data) print(table(i))`.

Comment: it worked but the problem is for loop assigns "i" to every variable so its difficult to observe the distribution of variables

Comment: @user3718501 `for(i in names(data)) {cat(i); print(table(data[[i]]))}`